# Electron+Angular Material2: Absolute/relative positionning randomly broken after default Material animations

Tags: angular, electron, angular-material2

Sometimes (randomly), when I use a material component in my angular5 app, the default animation is totally breaking the UI (relative & absolute positioning):

- Open/Close MatDialog animation
- Transition step animation on MatStepper
- Transition tab animation on MatTab

Stepper transition animation issue:

[image: Stepper transition animation issue]

Dialog open/close animation issue:

[image: dialog open close bug]

I have this behavior in multiple part of my app. It’s really irregular, sometimes it renders well, sometimes it fails all relative/absolute positioning (even the inspector can’t localize the elements properly):

[image: inspector]

If I disable the Stepper animation manually with `[@.disabled]="true"`, the bug between steps disappear:

[image: stepper animation off]

But the bug with open/close dialog remain. On the following gif, the stepper animation is disabled, and 3 open / close dialog successively, I’ve broken the input and I’m unable to write something in it and to validate the step:

[image: bug open close #2]

I haven't found any issue related with this behavior so I guess I have done a mistake few months ago and I can't put the finger on it.

What could cause such issues breaking positioning this way ?
I haven't any custom animations in my CSS and nothing in my component could change the position of my elements...

Comment: Any console errors? You telling that you use absolute positioned elements inside tabs and steppers, right? Is it really necessary to use absolute positioning all the way instead of flexbox/grid? Do you place your relative position flag in the right way? Does changing lost element z-index helps the situation?

Comment: No error in console. I already use flexbox/grid for most of my UI. I only use relative for pixel perfect and rarely absolute - the real issue is with relative positioning that are totally broken. Material Components use relative positioning internally (e.g. MatInput, MatSelect, MatCheckbox) so when the bug appear, I'm not able to use these controls anymore in my forms (cf gif 1 & 5). The strangest thing is the inspector which localize elements in the place they should be while they appear somewhere else on the screen (cf 3rd picture)

Comment: Have you tried using change detection after animation is complete?

Comment: Does it happen the same way in every browser (Which are not safari and edge - they're behavioring quite bad with angular animations)? And do you mean absolute positioning? Because relative is only a flag to set zero coordinates to specified element and absolute is for absolute positionin all along.

Comment: @VagrantAI By the way, the WebAnimations JS wrapper should help to solve angular animations in Safari and Edge.

Comment: @Edric seems like Angular developers consider this as bad practice https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22054

Comment: It's an electron application so chrome browser (getmateria.com - I'm migrating the app from angular1 to angular5). When I put my components on jsfiddle or stackblitz the bug is not present so it seems not related with the content of the dialog / stepper. I've upgraded electron few hours ago and haven't had the bug since. *cross finger*. I'll continue to test if the bug re-appear... I hope it was just that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Electron from v1.7.11 to v1.8.2 solved the issue for me. I could reproduce on multiple computers (Windows/Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in our Electron/Angular Material app. It's the issue of Electron itself as @Thibaud correctly noted. Happens when you have Material (mainly) form elements inside of some animated content (= modals, tabs, stepper, ..).

One way to resolve this is to apparently update to Electron 1.8.2 (which haven't worked in our case, but others have been successful with it.

The other one is to **disable animations** on the parent element – either explicitly on each via `[@.disabled]="true"` or [globally in the whole app](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-2-animations).